# Rolling back to older revision on deleted posts get 404 error and rollback fails

Tags: bug, revisions-list, rollbacks, deleted-posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Rollback link doesn't work on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60946/the-rollback-link-doesnt-work-on-deleted-posts)

Rolling back to older revision on deleted posts get 404 error on POST request, and rollback fails.

I could undelete it and rollback it back, and delete it again as work around.

But just curious is this proper way of how rollback button works?

Comment: I'm tempted to tag this [dead-horse-flogging] ;o) In other words, if it's deleted, I don't really see the point of reverting a revision. Could you clarify *where* you see a need for this?

Comment: @Piskvor, almost no point to do that, but I just wanted to say that  "rollback" button that I able to see on deleted posts does not work. that's all.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Since we can do edits on deleted posts, we should be able to do rollbacks on them, especially since rollbacks count as edits.