# Can't rollback edit on a deleted post

Tags: bug, edits, deleted-answers, rollbacks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Rollback link doesn't work on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60946/the-rollback-link-doesnt-work-on-deleted-posts)

I took the editor [from a deleted answer](https://superuser.com/a/385594/48078) (10k SU only) in order to use its preview to copy an HTML entitry representation, like `&harr;`.

Anyway, I accidentally pressed Enter and submitted this edit, which resulted in this:

[image]

Talk about a pointless edit right there. Anyway, to avoid confusion, I wanted to roll back, so I click the "edited" link, and then "rollback".

[image]

But nothing happens. The Javascript message "Are you sure …?" pops up, but when I click OK, the site doesn't reload, basically nothing happens.

Comment: Edits within the five minute grace period are removed by the way if you undo all your changes, even without a real rollback.